# Facing problem in getting service data into component

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-services

I am working on a project where ->

**

> 1.

** I have created a service file news.service.ts ,  (code below)
 **

> 2.

** In service I created function throwData() which returns the data of service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService implements OnInit {

  Data: any = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    console.log('f: ' );
    this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey=5a43238c7827436b9aac37e85583b74a').subscribe(data => {
      this.Data = data['articles'];
      console.log('from service = ' + this.Data[0] );
    });

  }

  throwData(): any {
    return this.Data;
  }
}
```

**

> 3.

** I have created a component file which is about to get data from service 
     I tried with the code below

**component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {NewsService} from '../service/news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  newData: any = [];

  constructor(private _NewsService: NewsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.newData = this._NewsService.throwData();

  }

}
```

**

> 4.

** Created a html file to display data in browser
**component.html** file

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 each-blog" *ngFor="let item of newData; let i = index"    style="margin-top: 17px ; background-color: #e3e0ef ;  border-left: 5px solid #3d7e9a; ; cursor: pointer;">
     <div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img" src="{{item.urlToImage}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
<a href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank"  style="margin-top:0px">{{item.title}}</a>
<p>{{item.content}}</p> 
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **But Problem is I am unable to display data into my browser**

Answer (score 0):

There are many angular concepts wrong in your code.

- The way you are doing the request in the service using the ngOnInit
  of the service
- The way you are exposing the data with the `throwData` function

[I recommend you reading the angular documentation about services.](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4)

That being said let me try to help you:

Your service should look something like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {
  data: any[];

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return !this.data
      ? this._http
          .get(
            'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey=5a43238c7827436b9aac37e85583b74a'
          )
          .pipe(
            switchMap(data => {
              this.data = data['articles'];
              return this.data;
            })
          )
      : of(this.data);
  }
}
```

Instead of fetching data on initilization, create a function that requests the data if the data is undefined or return it if it is already there.

In the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NewsService } from '../service/news.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  newData: any[];

  constructor(private _NewsService: NewsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this._NewsService.getData().subscribe(data => this.newData = data);
  }
}
```

Now you are just subscribing to the observable that the service return in the component.

The last change is in your HTML just add a ngIf before iterating through the array

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 each-blog" *ngIf="newData" *ngFor="let item of newData; let i = index"    style="margin-top: 17px ; background-color: #e3e0ef ;  border-left: 5px solid #3d7e9a; ; cursor: pointer;">
     <div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
<img class="img" src="{{item.urlToImage}}" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9">
<a href="{{item.url}}" target="_blank"  style="margin-top:0px">{{item.title}}</a>
<p>{{item.content}}</p> 
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>

    <div class="col-md-3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I didn't test it but this should work, or at least guide you into finding a solution. Cheers.

Comment: Hello @Santiago 
when I write  console.log(this.newData); 
in am getting result 'undefined' in console
Kindly help on this

Comment: @AnuragRanjan , where are you doing the console log?

Comment: I am writing it in the component.ts file , after I put the service data in the variable newData

Comment: And in the service, in the switch map, the API response data['articles'] have a value?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in the service just use http injection to perform the request 
it is going to return an observable then just in you component just subcribe to this Observable and thats it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NewsService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
  fetchDataFromServer(){
      this.http.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news- 
     in&apiKey=5a43238c7827436b9aac37e85583b74a')\
  }
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-footer',
  templateUrl: './footer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./footer.component.css']
})
export class FooterComponent implements OnInit {

  newData$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private _NewsService: NewsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {

   this.newData$ = this._NewsService.fetchDataFromServer();

  }

}
```

**Then in HTML template use this observable to show the info**

```
<div class="col-md-9 each-blog" *ngFor="let item of newData$ | async">
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you need to map the service into the `fetchDataFromServer` to get the articles  lile `.pipe(map (res => {return res['articles']}))`